# Rendering a partial after a successful form create with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render, partials

My controller code:

```
class HitChallengesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    game = Game.find(params[:id])
    suite_id = Suite.find_by(suite_number: params[:hit_challenge][:suite_id], game_id: game.id).id
    @hit_challenge = HitChallenge.new(game_id: game.id, suite_id: suite_id, title: params[:hit_challenge][:title])
    if @hit_challenge.save && request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @hit_challenge}
      end
    else
      redirect_to games_show_path(game)
    end
  end
end
```

View partial:

```
  <%if @game.has_hit_challenge %>
    <h4>Hit Challenges: </h4>

    <%if @hit_challenges.count > 1%>
      <% @hit_challenges.each do |h|%>
        <li>
        <%= "Suite #{h.suite.suite_number}, #{h.title}:" %>
        <%= link_to "Status", hit_status_path(h) %>
        <%= link_to "Play", play_hit_challenge_path(h) %>
        <%= form_for h, url: delete_hit_challenge_path(h), method: :delete do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :hit_challenge_id, value: h.id %>
          <%= f.submit "Delete" %>
        <%end%>
        </li>
      <%end%>
    <%else%>
      <li>
      <%= "Suite #{@hit_challenges.first.suite.suite_number}, #{@hit_challenges.first.title}:" %>
      <%= link_to "Status", hit_status_path(@hit_challenges.first) %>
      <%= link_to "Play", play_hit_challenge_path(@hit_challenges.first) %>
      <%= form_for @hit_challenges.first, url: delete_hit_challenge_path(@hit_challenges.first), method: :delete do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :hit_challenge_id, value: @hit_challenges.first.id %>
        <%= f.submit "Delete" %>
      <%end%>
      </li>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

Rest of the view:

```
<%if is_admin%>
  <div class='create-challenges'>
    <p>
      <%=form_for :suite, url: create_suite_path(:game_id => @game.id) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label 'Suite Number:' %>
        <%= f.text_field :suite_number %>
        <%=f.submit "Create" %>
      <%end%>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%=form_for :pitch_speed , url: create_pitch_speed_path(:game_id => @game.id) do |f|%>
        <%=f.label 'Create Pitch Speed Challenge' %>
        <%=f.select :suite_id, options_for_select(@game.suites.map {|s| s.suite_number}), {include_blank: 'Suite number?'} %>
        <%=f.label "Title:" %>
        <%=f.text_field :title %>
        <%=f.label "Min Speed:" %>
        <%=f.text_field :min_speed %>
        <%=f.label "Max Speed:" %>
        <%=f.text_field :max_speed %>
        <%=f.submit 'Create' %>
      <%end%>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%=form_for :prop_bet, url: create_prop_bet_path(:game_id => @game.id) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label 'Create Prop Bet:' %>
        <%= f.select :suite_id, options_for_select(@game.suites.map {|s| s.suite_number}), {include_blank: 'Suite number?'} %>
        <%= f.label "Title:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
        <%=f.submit "Create" %>
      <%end%>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%=form_for :hit_challenge, url: create_hit_challenge_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.label 'Create Hit Challenge:' %>
        <%= f.select :suite_id, options_for_select(@game.suites.map {|s| s.suite_number}), {include_blank: 'Suite number?'} %>
        <%= f.label "Title:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
        <%=f.submit "Create" %>
      <%end%>
    </p>
  </div>
  <%= link_to "Edit Game", games_edit_path(@game) %>
<div class='challenge-lists'>
  <div class='hit-list'>
    <%=render 'hit_challenges_list', locals: {@hit_challenges => @hit_challenges, @game => @game} %>
  </div>
  <div class='prop-list'>
  <%if @game.has_prop_bet%>

    <h4> Prop Bets:</h4>

    <%if @prop_bets.count > 1 %>
      <% @prop_bets.each do |prop| %>
        <li>
          <%= "Suite #{prop.suite.suite_number}, #{prop.title}:" %>
          <%=link_to "Status", prop_status_path(prop) %>
          <%=link_to "Play", show_prop_bet_path(prop) %>
          <%=link_to "Edit", edit_prop_path(prop) %>
          <%= form_for prop, url: delete_prop_bet_path(prop), method: :delete do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :prop_id, value: prop.id %>
            <%= f.submit "Delete" %>
          <%end%>
        </li>
      <%end%>
    <%else%>
      <li>
      <%="Suite #{@prop_bets.first.suite.suite_number}, #{@prop_bets.first.title}:" %>
      <%= link_to "Status", prop_status_path(@prop_bets.first) %>
      <%= link_to "Play", show_prop_bet_path(@prop_bets.first) %>
      <%=link_to "Edit", edit_prop_path(@prop_bets.first) %>
      <%= form_for @prop_bets.first, url: delete_prop_bet_path(@prop_bets.first), method: :delete do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :prop_id, value: @prop_bets.first.id %>
        <%= f.submit "Delete" %>
      <%end%>
      </li>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
  </div>
  <div class='pitch-list'>
    <%if @game.has_pitch_speed %>
      <h4> Pitch Speed Challenges </h4>
      <%if @game.pitch_speeds.count > 1 %>
        <%@pitch_speeds.each do |pitch| %>
          <%= "Suite #{pitch.suite.suite_number}, #{pitch.title}:" %>
          <%=link_to "Play", play_pitch_speed_path(pitch) %>
        <%end%>
      <%else%>
        <%= "Suite #{@game.pitch_speeds.first.suite.suite_number}, #{@game.pitch_speeds.first.title}:" %>
        <%=link_to "Play", play_pitch_speed_path(@game.pitch_speeds.first) %>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</div>
  <p>
    <li><%= link_to "Add Home Players", add_home_player_path(@game)%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Add Away Players", add_away_player_path(@game)%></li>
  </p>
  <p>
    Total Hits:
    <%=form_for @game, url: update_game_hits_path do |f| %>
      <%=f.text_field :total_hits%>
      <%=f.submit "Update Hits" %>
    <%end%>
  </p>
<%end%>
```

and finally my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.create-challenges').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      method: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(response){
      data = '<%= j(render partial: "hit_challenges_list")%>';
      console.log(data);
      $(".hit-list li").append(data);

    }).fail(function(){
      console.log('you fail in life')
    })
  })
```

I'm trying to create a a hit_challenge from that form and then try to append it to the list of hit_challenges as seen above. The partial works fine by itself and I can see the hit_challenges alright.

The ajax call goes through, the record is created but I can't figure out the append part. I think something is breaking while I'm trying to pass the newly created record data to the partial... what is appended is '<%= j(render partial: "hit_challenges_list")%>', it's like the ruby code inside doesn't work

Can it be because my partial is just too much? I tried passing locals in '<%= j(render partial: "hit_challenges_list")%>' but it made no difference. Btw I'm using rails 4.

EDIT:

Now I'm getting a weird syntax error, and I can't see what's wrong with the partial, I haven't changed anything and it works outside of that js method

SyntaxError (/Users/ddgs89/Desktop/Suite-Success/suite_success/app/views/games/_hit_challenges_list.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
...tput_buffer = @output_buffer; =  = local_assigns[:];;@output...
...                               ^
/Users/ddgs89/Desktop/Suite-Success/suite_success/app/views/games/_hit_challenges_list.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
...t_buffer; =  = local_assigns[:];;@output_buffer = output_buf...
...                               ^):
  app/views/games/_hit_challenges_list.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
  app/views/games/_hit_challenges_list.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
  app/views/hit_challenges/create.js.erb:9:in `_app_views_hit_challenges_create_js_erb___1940717404351023775_70144770896860'
  app/controllers/hit_challenges_controller.rb:8:in`create'

create.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.create-challenges').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      method: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(response){
      data = '<%= j(render partial: "games/hit_challenges_list", locals: {@hit_challenges => @hit_challenges, @game => @game})%>';
      console.log(data);
      $(".hit-list li").append(data);

    }).fail(function(){
      console.log('you fail in life')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're trying to do server-side rendering in the client side. An approach is to have your controller render the partial and serve it to the client, but a better approach and the Rails way is to use `remote: true` option on your form_fors *(not sure you're posting the right view as the create-challenges CSS class is not in the form you posted)*.

In your create action, you'd have:

```
def create
    game = Game.find(params[:id])
    suite_id = Suite.find_by(suite_number: params[:hit_challenge][:suite_id], game_id: game.id).id
    @hit_challenge = HitChallenge.new(game_id: game.id, suite_id: suite_id, title: params[:hit_challenge][:title])
    if @hit_challenge.save && request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @hit_challenge}
        format.js
      end
    else
      redirect_to games_show_path(game)
    end
  end
```

In your create.js.erb

```
data = '<%= j(render partial: "games/hit_challenges_list")%>';
console.log(data);
$(".hit-list li").append(data);
```

Let me know if that works or other clarifications needed

**UPDATE**

Your final create.js.erb should look like this:

```
  data = '<%=j render(partial: "games/hit_challenges_list")%>';
  console.log(data);
  $(".hit-list li").append(data);
```

You should ensure that `@hit_challenges` and `@game` are being set somewhere in your controller, I removed the instance variable passed to the partial because it's redundant, if you're passing local variables to a partial, it has to be a symbol.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the post to show the whole view. By the way I do have 'remote: true' on the form.

Thank you, I will update this as soon as I try the code..

Comment: cool. remember to add the local variables to the partial in the js.erb files too

Comment: Now I'm getting a 500 server error

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template hit_challenges/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/ddgs89/Desktop/Suite-Success/suite_success/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/hit_challenges_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Comment: My js file name is games_show.js, is that a problem? Not js.erb

Also another question: what is the reason we do format.json and then format.js on the next line?

Comment: where is the `hit_challenges_list` partial located?

Comment: views/games/_hit_challenges_list

Comment: the `create.js.erb` that I posted ought to be `app/views/hit_challengers/create.js.erb` and change the data to: `data = '<%= j(render partial: "games/hit_challenges_list")%>'`;

Comment: remember to pass the local variables to the partial too

Comment: see my edit on the question, it was too long for here

Comment: could you share the current setup of your `hit_challengers/create.js.erb`

Comment: Updated my answer as well

Comment: Another server error, can't find the variables in the partial
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `has_hit_challenge' for nil:NilClass):
    1:   <%if @game.has_hit_challenge %>
    2:     <h4>Hit Challenges: </h4>
    3: 
    4:     <%if @hit_challenges.count > 1%>
  app/views/games/_hit_challenges_list.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_games__hit_challenges_list_html_erb___3489646853059442939_70144809427420'
  app/views/hit_challenges/create.js.erb:9:in `_app_views_hit_challenges_create_js_erb___1940717404351023775_70144809450820'

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that you should set the `@game` and `@hit_challenges`, within your controller.

Comment: BTW, why do you have to re-render the hit_challenges list. A better approach would be to append only the newly created record to the list.

Comment: The `@game` and `@hit_challenges` are already set, and they are visible in the view, I think this error comes up when rails is trying to render the partial again.

Can you show me how to do your suggestion? I have tried it but failed earlier..

Comment: Yeah the variables' lifecycle is within the context of the request for the view, it's not persisted afterwards. i.e when you call the show action, the variables available for show would be accessible, the ones for create are not accessible to show nor vice-versa. In your case you're assuming the variables are available within the context of another request

Comment: So shouldn't I be passing them in the create.js.erb? Or should I set them in the HitChallenges#create method? How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah! Quick fix is to set it in HitChallenges#create

Comment: Ok so that error is fixed, I have the variables set. But the rendering is still funky. I submit the form once, nothing. When I submit it the second time, it appends it like this

Hit Challenges:

Hit Challenges:

Suite 22, second quarter: Status Play
Delete
Suite 22, Last Quarter: Status Play
Delete

Comment: could you check what's in your browser console?

Comment: First click nothing, second click the whole partial appears but like I said, like this:

Hit Challenges: 
Hit Challenges: Suite 22, second quarter: Status Play 
Delete 
Suite 22, Last Quarter: Status Play 
Delete

Comment: Do you have this on Github?

Comment: I'm sorry can't format it here. What happens is I click submit once, nothing happens. I click for a second time and then it appends the whole partial under the existing header

Comment: Yes, can I pm you (not sure I can do that on SO?) or email it to you?

Edit: here [link](https://github.com/aderend/Suite-Success)

Comment: Except for the second click i.e clicking twice, isn't that the behaviour you were aiming for? BTW, since you're re-rendering the hit_challenges_lists, I think you shouldn't be using the $.append, but $.html method

Comment: It was and I realized I should have used $.html, this thing happens on both occasions. Except with append it's original div is staying there and am updated one is appending to it. On the second click.

Comment: it's midnight by my time actually 3:20am. If the app is on Github, would help take a look at this when I wake up later in the morning. GH:andela-oakinniranye

Comment: You can upvote/accept the answer since the main issue has been solved

Comment: Really appreciate your help so far, here [link](https://github.com/aderend/Suite-Success)

Comment: I can't upvote yet, not enough rep but def deserved a check. Done.

Comment: check the javascript branch, not merged with master.